# How to merge two Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-native

Suppose I Have two Json. I want to merge this two json like the output given below.? How can i do this in javascript?

```
Json1 = {
 "2020-7-29": [{name: "Test1"}],
 ...
}

Json2 = {
 "2020-7-29": [{name: "Test2"}],
 ...
}

//Output = {
  "2020-7-29" : [{name: "Test1"}, {name: "Test2"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate on one of the objects and assign the current value to the other, or you can use the `extend` function :

```
Json3 = extend(Json1, Json2);
```

Good luck!